# angularjs http.get call not firing in ie10 due to browsing history setting

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, angularjs

I have an angularjs http.get call that i use to periodically make a call to a web service and update information in my ui. I want this call to be made every two minutes so the user gets the latest and greatest data without having to refresh the browser.
My target browser is ie10.
This works fine when the user's ie has the following setting:

Tools>Internet Options>General>Browsing History>Settings>check for newer versions of stored pages>Every time I visit the webpage

however when i change that setting to Automatically then the ui does not refresh. 
In fact with that setting to automatic i can't even see the calls going out to the service in Fiddler, other than the initial call out.

I will not know what the user has set in their browser and i don't even want to think about it. How can i force this to refresh every time regardless of that browser setting?

Answer (score 2):

this solved it for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18452373/729817

I tack on a random value in the query string of the url for the get request and ie is forced to fetch it each time.